# After Effect: My Shapes Messed Up In Lottie and Bodymovin

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects, ios

I create animation in AE and exported with bodymovin and now have json file.
but i have problem.
when i use it in " lottiefiles.com " it's worked well but when my iOs coder use it, some shapes messed up. like this:[image]
(I tested with LottiePreview iOS application)

Correct shape in lottiefiles and bodymovin preview:
[image]

I deleted merge path in my groups because bodymovin not support it. I don't know where is the problem, bodymovin, lottei, my file?

I hope somebody can help me. :(

P.S: I commented json and AE files.

Comment: Here is json file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1ddWzutYfGRREszcHNONGFqLW8

Here is AE file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1ddWzutYfGRRUNodmlEZEEyUms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Contact with Lottie support and find out problem is Lottei.
They said "if you use fill rules, Lottei Only support it in Android now but we hope to add support for it on iOS soon."

I use fill rules in illustrator. I changed it to stroke and problem solved!